# Handling blank columns in dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server

We have a stored procedure built using dynamic sql where our application passes in some column names. Occasionally blank or null values are passed through for the column name. In these cases the sp needs to return a null value for the column. I've tried various ways of handling this but whatever I do I seem to get the error below:

```
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.
```

Here is an example query with case when trying to handle null column names in the @Col2 param:

```
DECLARE 
@Col1 varchar(32) = 'name',
@Col2 varchar(32) = '',
@sqlCommand nvarchar(MAX) = ''


SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + N'
        SELECT ' + quotename(@Col1) + ' AS ' + quotename(@Col1) + ',
            CASE WHEN ' + quotename(@Col2) + ' IS NULL OR ' + quotename(@Col2) + ' = ''''
                THEN NULL
                ELSE ' + quotename(@Col2) + '
            END AS Col2

        FROM sys.columns c '

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand
```

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: Replace `EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand` with `print @sqlCommand` to view the SQL you're generating and you'll probably spot the issue pretty quickly...

Comment: Sql server 2014, thanks for your help

Comment: Your case expression should not be part of the dynamic sql. Look closely at the dynamic sql string this will create. Change the EXECUTE to SELECT and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Did you mean why you have that error messge? because you specify the col2 to be '', nothing wrong with your SP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
DECLARE 
@Col1 varchar(32) = 'name',
@Col2 varchar(32) = '',
@sqlCommand nvarchar(MAX) = ''


SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + N'
        SELECT ' + quotename(@Col1) + ' AS ' + quotename(@Col1) + ',' +
            CASE WHEN @Col2  IS NULL OR @Col2 = ''
                THEN 'NULL '
                ELSE quotename(@Col2) 
            END + ' AS Col2
        FROM sys.columns c '

--print @sqlCommand

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand
```

**Notes**

When you have an issue with Dynamic SQL, try using the `Print` statement to output the generated command to SSMS (or if you're not using SSMS, find some other way to pull back the generated SQL so you can see what's going on.

Doing this with your original code shows that the statement generated was:

```
SELECT [name] AS [name],
    CASE WHEN [] IS NULL OR [] = ''
        THEN NULL
        ELSE []
    END AS Col2
    FROM sys.columns c
```

... which you can probably see the issue with.

The problem was that you got confused between the SQL you were using to generate the Dynamic SQL, and the SQL required to be part of the Dynamic SQL statement being returned.

Comment: I'd also change the CASE statement for a COALESCE and NULLIF to clean the OP code up a bit: `COALESCE(NULLIF(quotename(@Col2), ''), NULL) Col2`

Comment: Thanks John, that's sorted it perfectly. I actually hadn't come across taking part of the statement out of the quotes with dynamic sql before, so that's a helpful thing to learn

Comment: No worries.  ps. I agree with @JohnJoseph's suggested improvement; much cleaner.  Minor typo though: the NULL should be in quotes to ensure it's treated as a string before adding to the dynamic SQL; i.e. `COALESCE(NULLIF(quotename(@Col2), ''), 'NULL') + ' Col2'`

Comment: This didn't work when I tested it originally, I think because the NULLIF tests if quotename('') = '' which wasn't returning a match. I'm not sure if this is right but I put quotename round the '' as below and it worked:

Comment: Ah yes; sorry, that's another bug where if @Col2 is blank it becomes [] which isn't blank, so doesn't get nulled; I'd missed that one.  Should be: `COALESCE(quotename(NULLIF(@Col2, '')), 'NULL') + ' Col2'`.